# Phone favorite - remove picture icon due to screen real estate

Tags: people-app, contact-photo

Using a new Nexus 4 with OS 4.2.2.

I've pulled my contacts onto the phone (from Exchange/OL using Companion Link) and they are synchronized to the phone's Contacts (people?) app.  I can see them from both the Google People app and from the phone app.

I have over 3000 contacts, and am trying to set up my favorites for people I call regularly (a list of about 20 contacts.)  This was very easy to do on my last Android phone, and the favorites would show me a list of contacts.

On this 4.2.2 phone, the favorites area is displayed with the contacts' pictures as a huge tile, with the contact names at the bottom of the tile.  I do not maintain pictures for my contacts, so I do not want to take up all of this screen real estate for non-existent pictures.  And, even if I had pictures, I wouldn't want them to appear as these huge tiles when I'm trying to look at a list of contacts.

How can I do one of the following things?

1. Force the phone/people apps to not show the picture tiles in lists.
2. Remove the picture tiles altogether.
3. Ensure that the picture tiles do not appear when there is no picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beneath those tiles will be a simple list labeled "Frequently Contacted", and they're listed with a much smaller photo (if one exists). So, as you use the phone, it will automatically build that list up for you of the people you contact the most.

Otherwise, there's not a way to change the layout of the app. Even if you were to create a contact group for those contacts, the group contact display uses the same sort of large photos.

Your other option would be a third-party app.

Comment: Got it; I will give that a shot and see if it will work.  It looks like I can still set up a default phone number for each person, and that is a much better display.  Not entirely within my control, which tends to make me cranky, but I suppose I'll manage.  :)  Thanks very much for your thoughts...